# Angular- wait for async task to complete

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise

Background:

Currently I have a an function that will return the top 5 customers from the database. However, the returned object only contain {userId, visitCount}. In order to retrieve the the username, I need to make another API call to get the user's profile based on on the userId. The final object ($scope.topFiveCustomer) will contain the following information {userId, visitCount, name}.

Problem:

After I retrieved the username, when I use console.log to print $scope.topFiveCustomers[0], this object only contain {userId, visitCount}. I am wondering is there any way to wait for retrieving the name (the following code) to finish before I do anything else?

```
_.each($scope.topFiveCustomers, function(customer) {
    CustomerService.getCustomer(customer.uuid)
        .then(function(response) {
            customer['name'] = response.data.name;
        })
});
```

Current code:

```
$scope.getTopFive = function() {
    DashboardService.getCustomerList($scope.topCustomerTime.value)
        .then(function(customerList) {
            $scope.topFiveCustomers = _.sortBy(customerList, 'visitCount').reverse().slice(0,5);

            _.each($scope.topFiveCustomers, function(customer) {
                CustomerService.getCustomer(customer.uuid)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        customer['name'] = response.data.name;
                    })
            });

            console.log($scope.topFiveCustomers);
            //name: test
            //uuid: 1234
            //visitCount: 5 

           console.log($scope.topFiveCustomers[0]);
           //uuid: 1234
           //visitCount: 5

    });
```

};

My attempt to resolve this issue by using $q:

```
function getCustomerName(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    _.each($scope.topFiveCustomers, function(customer) {
        CustomerService.getCustomer(customer.uuid)
            .then(function(response) {
                customer['name'] = response.data.name;
            })
    });

    deferred.resolve();

    return deferred.promise;
}


$scope.getTopFive = function() {
    DashboardService.getCustomerList($scope.topCustomerTime.value)
        .then(function(customerList) {
            $scope.topFiveCustomers = _.sortBy(customerList, 'visitCount').reverse().slice(0,5);

            getCustomerName()
                .then(function() {
                    new Chartist.Bar('#topCustomer', {
                      labels: [$scope.topFiveCustomers[0].uuid],
                      series: [$scope.topFiveCustomers[0].visitCount]
                    }, {
                      distributeSeries: true,
                      reverseData: true,
                      horizontalBars: true,
                      width: 250,
                      height: 250
                    });
                });                           
        });
};
```

Comment: You can simply return the value of $http as promise: $http.get().then(function () { return $http.get().then(); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take user of `$q.all` function which will wait till all five customer data gets retrieved.

**Code**

```
function getCustomerName() {
    var promises = [];
    _.each($scope.topFiveCustomers, function(customer) {
        //creating a promise array 
        promises.push(CustomerService.getCustomer(customer.uuid)
            .then(function(response) {
                customer['name'] = response.data.name;
            }))
    });
    return $q.all(promises); //returning combined 5 promises array.
};


$scope.getTopFive = function() {
    DashboardService.getCustomerList($scope.topCustomerTime.value)
      .then(function(customerList) {
      $scope.topFiveCustomers = _.sortBy(customerList, 'visitCount').reverse().slice(0, 5);

      getCustomerName() //will wait till all promises get resolved.
        .then(function(response) {
        angular.forEach($scope.topFiveCustomers, function(customer) {
          new Chartist.Bar('#topCustomer', {
            labels: [customer.uuid],
            series: [customer.visitCount]
          }, {
            distributeSeries: true,
            reverseData: true,
            horizontalBars: true,
            width: 250,
            height: 250
          });
        });
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!